# WP7 Web browser control uses IE browser, how to use different browser

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am trying for showing the content of html in web browser control. My content having encrypted value for img source. I don't what is this. That image not displaying in Webbrowser control. Also in IE browser. Normally Web browser control supports IE browser.

But it displayed for all browsers(Firefox, Chrome)

Is there way to use any(Firefox, Chorme) of the browser in Web Browser control.

Pls Help me.

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use - do you know the specific pages? I'm wondering if `WebBrowser.SaveToString()` would work for you to modify a page and decode the image yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WP7 you can only access and start standard WP7 applications, not any third party apps. So unless WP7 will be shipped with another browser, you can't do this.